# Can't add support library for CardView to my project

Tags: android, eclipse, android-support-library, android-library, android-cardview

I would like to add the support library for Cardview to my project (I am using Eclipse). I found this [TUTORIAL](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#libs-with-res) on Android website. I am doing everything according to it (I've already succesfully added AppCompat library to the project this way), but I am stuck at fourth point of adding this particular library to my project. In the window in which I should see the CardView library there is nothing:
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The Library Project you need to import in Eclipse (via Import->Existing Android Code into Workspace) is located in your Android SDK folder: ***Android\android-sdk\extras\android\support\v7\cardview***